# Записи о разделах в MBR (адреса в формате CHS)

Tags: загрузка, ос, формат, адрес, mbr

Как устроены адреса `CHS begin` и `CHS end` в записях о разделах в MBR? Я имею ввиду, скажем, первый байт - номер цилиндра, второй - головки, третий - сектора, или это устроено как-то по-другому? Где-то я видел, что некоторые биты "заимствуются" из соседних байтов, но я уже не в состоянии найти тот сайт, да и не понял я тогда ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дескриптор раздела в MBR выглядит так:

```
 uint8  IsBootable;   // 00 or 80h
 uint8  BeginHead;
 uint16 BeginSecCyl;  // CX for int 13h
 uint8  FileSystem;
 uint8  EndHead;
 uint16 EndSecCyl;
 uint32 BeginAbsSect;
 uint32 TotalSectors;
```

`BeginSecCyl` устроен так, чтобы подходить для применения в [`int 13h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm).

```
 les     BX, buf
 mov     AX, 0201h           ; 02 = read, 01 = 1 sector
 mov     CX, [BeginSecCyl]   ; значение из соответствующего поля
 mov     DH, [BeginHead]
 mov     DL, 80h             ; 80h для HDD + номер диска
 int     13h
```

считает вам бут-сектор выбранного раздела в `buf`.

В `BeginSecCyl` младшие 6 бит означают номер сектора, старшие 8 бит означают *младшие* 8 бит номера цилиндра, а оставшиеся 2 бита (6-7) — *старшие* два бита номера цилиндра.

---

Адресация CHS устарела, она позволяет подучить доступ лишь к 8 гигабайтам диска. Современные диски используют LBA-адресацию. LBA-адрес первого сектора лежит в `BeginAbsSect`.

Вы не можете читать большие диски через `int 31h`, но операционная система позволяет открыть весь диск как файл (Windows через `CreateFile`/`ReadFile` из [`"\\.\PhysicalDrive0"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#physical_disks_and_volumes), Unix через `/dev`), и читать сектора по нужному смещению. Новые операционные системы игнорируют значения CHS из MBR, и используют LBA-адреса.

---

Поскольку размер поля `BeginAbsSect` составляет 32 бита, это накладывает другой лимит адресации: 2 терабайта. (LBA-адрес может занимать до 48 бит.) Этот лимит нельзя преодолеть, оставаясь в формате MBR. Для дисков большего размера используется [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table).

Comment: Спасибо! <АнтиФильтрПоДлине>

Comment: @velikiyv4: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @velikiyv4: Обновил ответ.